# Substitution in integration 2

Tags: linear-transformations, substitution

It seems like I dont quite understand the third line in [Proof](https://www.math.kth.se/math/student/courses/5B1472/F/200506/Exercise/Laplace.pdf).

> Now
>   $$\int_0^\infty e^{-st} t^{1/2} dt = s^{-1/2} \int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{-1/2} du  $$

$ u:= st$, $du/dt=s$ therefore $ dt= du/s $
I can't come up with the right term

since

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-st} t^{1/2} =\int_0^\infty e^{-u} \frac{t^{1/2}}{s} du$$

But $ u \ne t/s$

Would be nice to have some explaination. thank you.
Greetings.

Comment: As $u=st$, we have $t = u/s$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u=st$, hence $t=u/s$:

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-st} t^{1/2} dt 
=\int_0^\infty e^{-u} \frac{(u/s)^{1/2}}{s} du
=s^{-3/2} \int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{1/2} du
=s^{-3/2}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.
$$

Comment: That was quick and clear. Thank you.

Comment: sry. I still dont get it. How can you go from $(u/s)^{1/2} /s = u^{1/2}/s^{3/2}$ to $u^{-1/2}$. This is embarassing for me.

Comment: What is written in your notes is wrong. The mistake is that the original integral has $t^{-1/2}$, not $t^{1/2}$.

Comment: Oh my god. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :) You can verify similarly the calculations for the other case (which has the wanted result).

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-st} t^{1/2} \, dt = s^{-3/2} \int_0^\infty e^{-st}(st)^{1/2} (s\,dt) = s^{-3/2} \int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{1/2} \, du $$